# Tensorflow Object Detection Training using EfficientDet D7 1536x1536 keeps crasing on Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, google-colaboratory

**Prerequisites:**

Please answer the following questions for yourself before submitting an issue.

[yes ] I am using the latest TensorFlow Model Garden release and TensorFlow 2.

[ yes] I am reporting the issue to the correct repository. (Model Garden official or research directory)

[ yes] I checked to make sure that this issue has not been filed already.

**1. The entire URL of the file you are using**

https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

**2. Describe the bug**

You will find the error message for batch_size = 16 underneath
I also tried to train the model for batch_sizes = 2, 4, 8, 32 and 64 with similar error messages

**batch_size: 16:**

```
    2020-12-13 02:15:18.183495: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
    2020-12-13 02:15:23.944431: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
    2020-12-13 02:15:24.008491: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:24.009074: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
    pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
    coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.73GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
    2020-12-13 02:15:24.009116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
    2020-12-13 02:15:24.223292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:24.368251: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:24.382205: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:24.664816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:24.682122: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.166466: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.166781: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.167471: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.167986: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.271108: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2199995000 Hz
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.271347: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x21a9480 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.271377: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.393955: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.394603: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x21a9640 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.394634: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla T4, Compute Capability 7.5
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395136: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395648: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
    pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
    coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.73GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395692: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395781: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395821: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395845: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395866: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395887: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.395963: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.396507: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.396998: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
    2020-12-13 02:15:25.397170: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
    2020-12-13 02:15:29.195607: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
    2020-12-13 02:15:29.195670: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
    2020-12-13 02:15:29.195683: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
    2020-12-13 02:15:29.201423: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:29.202139: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-12-13 02:15:29.202644: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
    2020-12-13 02:15:29.202692: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 13962 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla T4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 7.5)
    INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
    I1213 02:15:29.206272 139735221852032 mirrored_strategy.py:341] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
    INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
    I1213 02:15:29.214179 139735221852032 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
    INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
    I1213 02:15:29.214378 139735221852032 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
    I1213 02:15:29.292731 139735221852032 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:144] EfficientDet EfficientNet backbone version: efficientnet-b6
    I1213 02:15:29.292883 139735221852032 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:145] EfficientDet BiFPN num filters: 384
    I1213 02:15:29.292959 139735221852032 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:147] EfficientDet BiFPN num iterations: 8
    I1213 02:15:29.307233 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=32 output=56
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.373963 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.376944 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.381036 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.383636 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.402147 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.404556 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.413167 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=32 output=56
    I1213 02:15:29.413269 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=16 output=32
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.435267 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.438397 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.444043 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.446650 139735221852032 cross_device_ops.py:443] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
    I1213 02:15:29.891611 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=16 output=32
    I1213 02:15:29.891779 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=24 output=40
    I1213 02:15:30.934064 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=24 output=40
    I1213 02:15:30.934247 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=40 output=72
    I1213 02:15:31.967833 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=40 output=72
    I1213 02:15:31.968006 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=80 output=144
    I1213 02:15:33.458566 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=80 output=144
    I1213 02:15:33.458740 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=112 output=200
    I1213 02:15:34.845838 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=112 output=200
    I1213 02:15:34.846012 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=192 output=344
    I1213 02:15:36.863851 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=192 output=344
    I1213 02:15:36.864024 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=320 output=576
    I1213 02:15:37.384583 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=1280 output=2304
    I1213 02:15:37.459576 139735221852032 efficientnet_model.py:458] Building model efficientnet with params ModelConfig(width_coefficient=1.8, depth_coefficient=2.6, resolution=528, dropout_rate=0.5, blocks=(BlockConfig(input_filters=32, output_filters=16, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=1, expand_ratio=1, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=16, output_filters=24, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=2, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=24, output_filters=40, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=2, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=40, output_filters=80, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=3, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=80, output_filters=112, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=3, expand_ratio=6, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=112, output_filters=192, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=4, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=192, output_filters=320, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=1, expand_ratio=6, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise')), stem_base_filters=32, top_base_filters=1280, activation='simple_swish', batch_norm='default', bn_momentum=0.99, bn_epsilon=0.001, weight_decay=5e-06, drop_connect_rate=0.2, depth_divisor=8, min_depth=None, use_se=True, input_channels=3, num_classes=1000, model_name='efficientnet', rescale_input=False, data_format='channels_last', dtype='float32')
    INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['annotations/train.record']
    I1213 02:15:37.596717 139735221852032 dataset_builder.py:148] Reading unweighted datasets: ['annotations/train.record']
    INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['annotations/train.record']
    I1213 02:15:37.597848 139735221852032 dataset_builder.py:77] Reading record datasets for input file: ['annotations/train.record']
    INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
    I1213 02:15:37.597994 139735221852032 dataset_builder.py:78] Number of filenames to read: 1
    WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
    W1213 02:15:37.598072 139735221852032 dataset_builder.py:86] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
    WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:103: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
    W1213 02:15:37.601274 139735221852032 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:103: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
    WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:222: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
    W1213 02:15:37.629114 139735221852032 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:222: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
    WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
    W1213 02:15:43.718269 139735221852032 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
    WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/inputs.py:281: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use `tf.cast` instead.
    W1213 02:15:47.488671 139735221852032 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/inputs.py:281: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use `tf.cast` instead.
    ^C
```

I also tried out batch sizes 8,32 and 64 getting similar error messages.

**3. Steps to reproduce**

follow colab guide tensorflow object detection tutorial:
https://medium.com/swlh/tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-with-google-colab-b2af171e81cc
and
https://github.com/Nkap23/TensorFlow_with_Colab_tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow_with_Colab_tutorial.ipynb

I did use a custom dataset of my own that is active in my collab folder rather than the one used by the guide of the tutorial Nkap23. Consisting of 58 classes. I do not know if the problem is related to this.
On my home computer using the SSD ResNet50 V1 FPN 640x640 Model everything worked fine and it was
able to train and detect using 6 of the 58 classes used in the EfficientDet D7.

**4. Expected behavior**

The data set is supposed to train a model using the train samples and XML files that will then be used to
do inference on the test images, hopefully with near-perfect results.

**5. System information**

OS Platform and Distribution: Colab run from google chrome on Windows 10 Home Build 19041
TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): TensorFlow 2.3.0
TensorFlow version (use command below):
2020-12-13 02:33:57.662779: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
v2.3.0-0-gb36436b087 2.3.0

Python version: Python 3.6.9
CUDA/cuDNN version: CUDA Version 10.1.243
GPU model and memory:
I don't know the model of the GPU. I assume you will know the model. I was able to collect some statistics about the GPU when not in use:

Gen RAM Free: 12.4 GB | Proc size: 208.9 MB
GPU RAM Free: 15079MB | Used: 0MB | Util 0% | Total 15079MB

I hope someone has encountered a similar issue in the past and can help me out.

Comment: These are not error messages, how long did you leave this code running?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Snoopy about 5-10 min. But the running play icon in colab indicating that it is running a process stops working after the ^C appears? You mean to tell me I should just ignore it?